# Why jsf:binding attribute creates jsessionid cookie when used on input field?

Tags: jsf-2, jsf-2.2

Why jsessionid cookie is created when I visit page that has `jsf:binding` attribute? If I remove `jsf:binding` no cookie is created. I'd like to have my page cookieless. The backing bean is annotated with these two Spring annotations: `@Controller` and `@Scope("request")`.

```
<div class="form-group #{!username.valid ? 'has-error' : ''}">
    <label for="username" class="col-md-2 control-label">
        #{i18n['signup.username.text']}
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="text"
            class="form-control"
            jsf:id="username"
            jsf:binding="#{username}"
            jsf:value="#{signUpBean.username}"
            jsf:maxlength="#{signUpBean.USERNAME_MAXLENGTH}"
            placeholder="#{i18n['signup.username.placeholder.text']}">
            <f:ajax event="change" render="username-message" />
        </input>
    </div>
    <h:message for="username" id="username-message" styleClass="col-md-6 help-block" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `UIComponent usernameInput` to the backing bean, changed `jsf:binding="#{username}"` to `jsf:binding="#{signUpBean.usernameInput}"` and changed `#{!username.valid ? 'has-error' : ''}` to `#{!signUpBean.usernameInput.valid ? 'has-error' : ''}` and no cookie is created anymore.